# Rails 5 Autocomplete Issues

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm following the guide on [this Git](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete) and I'm having a bit of an issue. Right now as soon as I access my 'search form' it's automatically erroring out with

**My View**

```
##Working Script
<%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:name, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:name) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>

##Script from the Github that I modified (Broke?)
<%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :card, :as => :autocomplete, :source_query => autocomplete_card_name_card_path %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Save', :class=> 'btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
class CardsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :card, :name, :full => true
```

Currently if I leave the view in that's "broke" it automatically returns the top 10 cards alphabetically. I don't get the search form or anything. I was thinking maybe it's because the view and routes go to /search causing it to 'auto complete' with a space as the 'name'?

So I moved the View but now it always errors on the f.errors due to nil.

Thoughts/opionions? /// Is there some 'helper' that could have done this in the first place? I'm on Rails 5, and trying to access data within ActiveRecord.

**UPDATE**

Making the view into

```
    <h1>New Card</h1>

<%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:name, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :card, :as => :autocomplete, :source_query => autocomplete_card_name_cards_path %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

I now get the search field, however it -isn't- autocompleting, and when I submit it isn't searching - It's just showing me the top 10 again alphabetically.

(In case it's important, this table has ~35K things)